# Determine which device AirPods have connected to using Siri

Tags: macos, ios, siri, watchos, airpods

When I put on my AirPods, they automatically connect to the device that they were most recently connected to. However, without checking each device, I'm not sure *which* device they've connected to.

I'm looking for a command I can say to Siri that will differentiate the device so that I know which device they have connected to. Ideally, it would be something like

- *Which device are my AirPods connected to?*

but if that's not possible then another phrase that identifies the connected device. It has to be something that only needs voice/hearing, not looking at any device's screen.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS devices you can use [this shortcut](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/d01937a621a04808a56c8bcc6d6edc8a).  I am not able to test it on macos, but it works on my iPad Pro and my iPhone X. When I try it on my Series 3 Apple Watch it just hangs. Just assign it whatever custom text you want Siri to recognize.

Comment: This doesn't actually differentiate between iPhone and Apple Watch. I tried it on mine (Series 4) and it gives the same response as running it on the iPhone

Comment: iOS behavior is weird. When I disconnect the AirPods from my iPhone and ask Siri to run the shortcut when only connected to my Apple Watch, it hangs.  After reconnecting to my phone, when the Airplay icon on my Apple Watch is highlighted blue, and my AirPods are selected it uses my iPhone to run the Shortcut, so that is where it pulls the device name from. I have no idea why iOS would have AIrPods connected to the iPhone but allow the Apple Watch to Airplay to the AirPods.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the AirPods are connected to the Apple Watch, but it's a shortcut that can't be run on the Watch, so it runs it on the iPhone (thereby giving the same result as running it directly on the iPhone)